# What is WebProxy/1.0 Pre-Alpha?

Tags: networking, proxy

I have had 504 errors from my domain throughout the day. The back end servers look okay and the CDN provider (Fastly) doesn't think it could be them. Looking a little closer I see the following header in the 504:

```
Server: WebProxy/1.0 Pre-Alpha
```

Would anyone happen to know who is running that software or have you had any successful resolutions of a similar issue? If so, what was the solution?

The client is a Windows 10 laptop tethered to an iPhone 6plus on the EE network in the UK.

Comment: I'm seeing the same `Server: WebProxy/1.0 Pre-Alpha` with a `503 Service Unavailable` for an http request where I'm expecting a connection failure.  I'm using a Sprint hotspot in the US.

Comment: I'm tethered to an EE mobile in the UK and am seeing the same results when I execute a `curl -v http://my_server`. The firewall protecting my server doesn't expose port 80, so I can only conclude that EE are running a proxy.

Comment: Were you using docker containers by any chance? Or were you behind a firewall/security policy? My similar experience was caused by my docker container ports not being exposed. So even though I was able to access from EC2 instances locally, I was not able to from the internet. I'm guessing WebProxy is an internal tool AWS uses as a transparent proxy.